# How to add a key value pair at the end of a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am working on array for a project and I want to know how I can add a key value pair at the end of an array.
So here are the elements:

```
1st array
    $items = array(
    array('id' => '1', 'desc'=>'Canadian-Australian Dictionary', 'price'=>24.95),
    array('id' => '2', 'desc'=>'As-new parachute (never opened)', 'price'=> 1000),
    array('id'=>'3', 'desc'=>'Songs of the Goldfish (2CD set)', 'price'=> 19.99));

2nd array:
 $cart = array(
array('id' => '1','quantity'=>2)
);
```

So basically what I want to know is how can I add values from 1st array to 2nd array based on the id to have a array like this one.

```
final array i want to get:
$itemDetail = array(
array('id' => '1', 'desc'=>'Canadian-Australian Dictionary', 'price'=>24.95, 'quantity'=> 1)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it simple with loop:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($cart as $attributes) {
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if ($item['id'] == $attributes['id']) {
            $result[] = $item + $attributes;
        }
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't meet requirements. The arrays have to be filled based on id (so some `if` is necessary) and moreover updated is supposed to be second array, not first.

Comment: nice answer, we can solve this problem after sorting second array base on id As I mention in first answer

Answer (score 1):

Work For both array look like above in sequence id start with 1

```
$items = array(
        array('id' => '1', 'desc'=>'Canadian-Australian Dictionary', 'price'=>24.95),
        array('id' => '2', 'desc'=>'As-new parachute (never opened)', 'price'=> 1000),
        array('id'=>'3', 'desc'=>'Songs of the Goldfish (2CD set)', 'price'=> 19.99));


     $cart = array(
    array('id' => '1','quantity'=>2)
    );

    function my_array_merge(&$array1, &$array2) {
        $result = Array();
        foreach($array1 as $key => &$value) {
            $result[$key] = array_merge($value, $array2[$key]);
        }
        return $result;
    }
    $array = my_array_merge($items, $cart);
    print_r($array);
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't meet requirements. The arrays have to be filled based on id (so some `if` is necessary). In your case it's working only due to you merge first item from first array and first item from second array. But if in first array item `'id'=>'1'` is on first position and in second array on different position than first, your code doesn't work.

Comment: Still that's not it:-) Try to imagine, you have in `$cart` only one array with `'id' => '2'`. Then this array will merge with array `'id' => '1'` from `$items`, because both are first in their multiarrays. This is not desired behavior. It's necessary check, if 'id' from $cart == 'id' from $items.

Comment: I m not getting, If U show me both array my be I could help

Comment: Try this `$cart` array.  `$cart = array(
array('id' => '2','quantity'=>2)
);` This will not match correctly with `$items`.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not working. Try it. You have `$cart` as `$cart = array(
 array('id' => '2', 'quantity' => 2),
);`. So you want to match with second from the `$items`, but it match with first from `$items`. You want output `array('id' => '2', 'desc' => 'As-new parachute (never opened)', 'price' => 1000, 'quantity' => 2)`. You get according to your code `array('id' => '2', 'desc' => 'Canadian-Australian Dictionary', 'price' => 24.95, 'quantity' => 2)`. This is not desired output.

Comment: Yes u are right I am talking about second answer on page not in section of my answer

Comment: Ok, now I understand, about which answer you talked:-)